# How to change background color of bottom bar home/back with react-native android?

Tags: react-native

Please see the attached file, how we can change its background color in `react-native`?

[image: bottom widgets control]

Answer (score 1):

If you use any navigation library
Do this through the navigation library

If not you can use this [react-native-navigation-bar-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-bar-color)

**Update:**

in react-navigation, this is not possible

in [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/160) you can see here

Comment: Thank you, Is that possible with react-navigation ?

Comment: in react navigation probably this is not possible